# What do the markings in 75mm WW1 trench art mean?

Tags: world-war-one, identification, art

Great Uncle brought home Trench art from Verdun with a Lorraine cross. Markings are 75 DE and A RS /333. 15. There are 5 punch marks and what looks like a small K near the primer. Can anyone explain the meaning of the marks?

Comment: Please provide a photo and dimensions of the object. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Quite a bit of information can be gleaned from the description here (though a photo and measurements would still help greatly).

---

- 75 DE --(is there a C following this? and what are the dimensions?) points towards a French 75mm shell, perhaps used in something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/75_mm_Field_Gun_M1897_on_M2_Carriage)
- A.RS  --was identified in the
  answer [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/42158/16951) as
  '*manufactured in Rennes (Ateliers de construction de Rennes).*'
- /333      --likely a lot number, as per discussion [here](https://forum.cartridgecollectors.org/t/75mm-field-gun-shell-marking-identification-help/33961/9#:%7E:text=The%206%200%E2%80%99clock%20markings%20are%20%3A%0ACase%20manufacturer.%20Lot%20number.%20Date.%20Metal%20furnisher.)
- .15     --is the year of manufacture, 1915.
- five punch marks and small k near primer  --unclear, need photo for
  context

---

Most of this can be compared to the answers about a similar  shell in [What can I learn from these WW1 shell cases?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/42150/16951)

A discussion on the [greatwarforum](https://www.greatwarforum.org/topic/115305-brass-shell-cases-ww1/) has info concerning the *75 DE C* designation.

ARS is also mentioned in the [headstamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headstamp) codes listed [here](https://www.cartridgecollectors.org/headstampcodes#:%7E:text=ARS,Rennes%2C%20Rennes%2C%20France)

A discussion on marking on similar 75mm shell casings can also be found at [forum.cartridgecollectors.org](https://forum.cartridgecollectors.org/t/75mm-field-gun-shell-marking-identification-help/33961/9#:%7E:text=The%206%200%E2%80%99clock%20markings%20are%20%3A%0ACase%20manufacturer.%20Lot%20number.%20Date.%20Metal%20furnisher.)