# Can you identify the markings on this WW1 trench art?

Tags: world-war-one, identification, french, shell-casings

[image][image]enter image description here[image]Can anyone help me decode these markings?

Comment: You've tagged this as French, is that because it was found in France or because you know it was manufactured by the French?

Comment: Can you explicit where you found this photo, or where you found the artefact if you took the photo yourself ?

Comment: I have the artifact in my possession, it is a friend's heirloom that was passed down from their grandfather whom served in WW1 battle of Verdun

Comment: And I'm assuming it's French because it's from the WW1 battle of Verdun

Answer (score 5):

According to [this thread on another forum](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/4l4ufd/need_help_understanding_markings_on_french_75mm/), the 75 DE C is for the gun model ([75mm de campagne/field gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_de_75_mod%C3%A8le_1897)), A RS is probably for the manufacturer (Ateliers de construction de Rennes, according to [this answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/70047/what-do-the-markings-in-75mm-ww1-trench-art-mean)), 1181 is a lot number and 16 is the production year (1916).

Note that these are all very weak sources, but you might find better ones [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/70047/what-do-the-markings-in-75mm-ww1-trench-art-mean) or [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/42150/what-can-i-learn-from-these-ww1-shell-cases).

Comment: Would you happen to know what the small "T"s mean? And the "S" with the Anchor?